# get sum of float values in table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of fines people owe:

```
<tr><td class='fines'>104.20</td></tr>
<tr><td class='fines'>26.40</td></tr>
<tr><td class='fines'>99.14</td></tr>
```

I am trying to get the sum of the cells:

```
var sumFines = "";
$.each($('.fines'),function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    sumFines += parseFloat($(this).html());
})
alert(sumFines);
```

The result of each alert in each loop is the number in the cell. The result of the final alert is "`NaN`", Why?

Comment: Set the initial value to `0`, not an empty string.

Comment: yep, thank you just figured it out.

Comment: If using jQuery, `$(this).text()` would be more appropriate, you really don't want the actual markup (e.g. the total might be `<b>$10.99</b>`). And if performance matters at all, `this.textContent` is hugely faster.

Answer (score 2):

When you sum

```
"" + 120
```

the result return a string, you must sum number, so change

```
var sumFines = "";
```

to

```
var sumFines = 0;
```

Comment: You can use mark down and the `{}` button to format text as code (or use a new line that starts with 4 spaces.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new on this page, I will make as you said next times :)

Answer (score 1):

I need to set initial value of sumFines to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sumFines = 0;
$.each($('.fines'),function(){
    alert($(this).html());
    sumFines += parseFloat($(this).html());
})
alert(sumFines);
```

`var sumFines = "";` makes sumFines a string and that's the reason you get NaN because you are doin arithmatic operations with a string and float which can't be cast together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the .each approach, just change your initial value to 0.

```
var subtotal = 0;
$('.fines').each(function() {
    subtotal += !isNaN(+$(this).html()) && +$(this).html();
});

alert(subtotal);
```

The line:

```
!isNaN(+$(this).html()) && +$(this).html();
```

asserts that you are effectively adding a number, else nothing.

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hem7q4fn/2/

Answer (score 1):

Nan reduce whole expression to NaN
try:

```
var sumFines = 0;
$('.fines').each(function () {
    var num = parseFloat($(this).txt());
    sumFines += isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
});
alert(sumFines);
```